# Откатить Git pull

Tags: git

У меня есть рабочая ветка, там есть несколько коммитов, а потом есть git pull другой ветки и еще несколько моих коммитов.

Можно ли убрать все изменения которые пришли с git pull? убрать, откатить, но нужно оставить все мои коммиты до и после этого git pull.

История

1. new branch (of master)
2. commit 1
3. commin 2
4. git pull other branch
5. commit 3
6. commit N

можно ли убрать 4 строку (git pull) как будто я этого не делал?)

git reset soft до 4?

Comment: самый простой способ - сделать rebase

Answer (score 0):

Если известно к какому коммиту нужно вернуться, то просто `git reset --hard commit_id`.

Будьте внимательным: `reset --hard` безвозвратно удалит файлы из удаляемых коммитов.

Comment: ну так у меня удаляться мои коммиты 3..N и все файлы.. ?